# Sum of sequence till $N$ terms

Tags: summation

Let $$T_n = 1 \cdot 3 \cdot \dots (2n+1)$$

> What will be  $\sum_{n=1}^N T_n$?

If we put value to understand we get
$$
(1\cdot3 )+ (1\cdot3\cdot5 )+ (1\cdot3\cdot5\cdot7)\dots +  (1\cdot3\cdot5\cdot7 \dots(2n+1))
$$

> I have tried to do something, but couldn't even able to write first step.

Comment: So sounds like $T_n = \dfrac{(2n+1)!}{2^n n!}$

Comment: What makes you think there is a closed-form expression for your sum ([OEIS A076795](https://oeis.org/A076795)$ -2$)?

Comment: @Henry thanks for the OEIS link -- it also gives the exponential generating function...

Answer (score 2):

*Just for your curiosity.*

If you enjoy special functions
$$S_N=\sum_{n=1}^N T_n=\sum_{n=1}^N \dfrac{(2n+1)!}{2^n \,n!}$$
$$S_N=\frac{2^{N+1} E_{N+\frac{5}{2}}\left(-\frac{1}{2}\right) \Gamma \left(N+\frac{5}{2}\right)}{\sqrt{e \pi }}-\frac{E_{\frac{3}{2}}\left(-\frac{1}{2}\right)}{2 \sqrt{e}}-1$$ where appear the exponential integral function.

It can also write
$$S_N=\sqrt{\frac{\pi }{2 e}}\left(i+ \text{erfi}\left(\frac{1}{\sqrt{2}}\right)\right)-i\frac{ (-1)^N \Gamma \left(\frac{2N+5}{2}\right) \Gamma \left(-\frac{2N+3}{2},-\frac{1}{2}\right)}{\sqrt{2 e \pi }}-2$$

Comment: It is like a bouncer for me but thanks